# Heavy Lies the Crown - what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expressions

I watched 'The Crown' and faced the expression 'heavy lies the crown' several times throughout the series.
What does it mean and how can we use it in a daily sentence?!

Comment: Even though the word order is different, this is just like saying "the crown lies heavy [on the head]".  You should not use this word order in "daily" English.

Answer (score 13):

It's a metaphoric usage, same as *the **burden** of office*. It's also why we speak of *carrying **heavy** responsibility*.

You should work out for yourself why Anglophones find these metaphors appropriate, and what exactly the connotations are, if such usages don't exist in your own language.

Note that the cited ***heavy lies the crown*** is effectively a misquote from Shakespeare's ***Uneasy lies the head that wears a crown*** (Henry IV, Part 2) that *didn't* feature the "weight" metaphor. But I expect people will soon be quoting the TV series rather than Shakespeare, not least because the misquote seems perfectly "natural" to those unfamiliar with the original.

---

This is "elevated, poetic" language" - not really appropriate in "conversational" contexts except facetiously (or when deliberately quoting / alluding to either / both of those earlier usages).

Having said that, although ordinary people in ordinary conversational contexts wouldn't normally speak so poetically<sup>1</sup> about "high office", you might hear things like...

> *"What's up with John? He looks so miserable. Anyone would think he's got [**the weight of the world on his shoulders**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22carries%20the%20weight%20of%20the%20world%22)".*

---

<sup>1</sup> [As commented by @BadZen,](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/349588/heavy-lies-the-crown-what-does-it-mean#comment680645_349588) both the actual text as cited and Shakespeare's "original" are "literary inversions" (of *The crown lies heavy, The head that wears the crown lies uneasy*). Such inversions are relatively uncommon in natural conversation, regardless of how lofty and/or metaphoric the utterance is, so *use them at your peril*.